# Hypermedia Message Builders in WSO2 axis configuration

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, apache-synapse

Is there any way to set axis2 message builder/formatter for hypermedia, without setting content types one by one?

Example:

```
application/vnd.xxx.v1+json
application/vnd.yyy.v2+json
```

With something like:

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/vnd.*+json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder" />
```

?